# Паста (а)матричана — у автора она с прописной. Как правильно?

Tags: прописная-строчная

"Делают на этой земле и особую пасту. На римском диалекте ее называют Матричана. По имени местечка, откуда она «родом», – Amatrice".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Справочная служба Грамоты.ру давала такие рекомендации:

*Выступающие в качестве собственных имен названия кулинарных блюд корректно во всех случаях писать с прописной в кавычках: спагетти «Карбонара», пицца «Карбонара», спагетти «Болоньезе», пицца «Болоньезе», пицца «Маргарита».*

То есть по аналогии: "Аматричана" (на просторах Интернета всё же больше распространено с А, на итальянский манер), "Матричана" (как произносится в римском диалекте).